# Java sidebar program Sidebar.exe *32

Tags: java, sidebar

Do you recognize the program "C:\Program Files\Java\sidebar.exe" - I can't find anything about it by searching, and nothing in my event logs suggests what might have causes this file to exist. Apparently I had a restart just before the time it was created, but I didn't have any installs in the session prior to that restart.

I noticed it due to my CPU fan rising fast. Stuck around 13% CPU usage.
Virus total: https://www.virustotal.com/da/file/26c7282daa667210785080f0dbe8e6f85c8a3949e433b198ee91d9ebffd1b5b5/analysis/1372769247/

Currently I handle it as a virus.
(resolved, see comments below)

Comment: So what's your question exactly? If it's a virus or some kind of malware?

Comment: Why don't you just remove Java then reinstall Java.  Be sure to delete the Java directory between these operations.

Comment: @Ramhound He has a bitcoin miner virus, it's unrelated to Java. He needs to clean his system.

Comment: @mantan129 Whether you recognized the program or not. Lack of information makes it difficult for me to trace what its functionality is and how I got it.
#Darth Android Thanks, I have also come to that conclusion after studying that topic a bit more. Using FileInsight I found the config folder, and it is uses http://www.ztex.de/btcminer/ and https://github.com/progranism/Open-Source-FPGA-Bitcoin-Miner/tree/master/projects/X6000_ztex_comm4/hdl

The userid used in the bit files are not resembling a bitcoin user id, (ex: 0xFFFFFFFF) - The program doesn't seem to be dangerous in it self.

Comment: @DarthAndroid - Based on its location I would also gather its a virus written in Java.  Which is part of the reason I told him to reinstall Java, since its very likely, he is using an vulerable version of Java.

Comment: @Ramhound If it's a virus, then its location is meaningless. Viruses install wherever they think they can hide best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [Malwarebytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/) (free version). It should deal with a these kind of malware / viruses, etc.